# Need suggestion regarding images assets for different resolution of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, screen-resolution

I need a suggestion on how to use images in different resolution iPhones.

As we know for iPhone3gs and iPhone 4 we need @1x images.

For iPhone4s, and iPhone 5,6 we need @2x images.

For iPhone 6+ we need @3x images.

I am thinking of adding images assets in two ways.

**Way 1** -

```
abc.png         size 20X20

abc@2x.png      size 40X40

abc@3x.png      size 60X60
```

while accessing the image we use

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
```

Here in non retina display ios will automatically pick the abc.png 
for iphone 4s,5,6 it will pick abc@2x.png automatically
for iphone6+ it will pick abc@3x.png automatically

**Way 2** -

```
abc.png         size 20X20

abc@2x.png      size 40X40

abc_iphone5or6.png         size 25X25
size is bigger because resolution is big, we need to show big icon , if we use way 1 then it will show 20X20 size icon and will look smaller on big screens

abc_iphone5or6@2x.png      size 50X50 


abc_iphone6+.png         size 35X35 
size is bigger because resolution is big, we need to show big icon , if we use way 1 then it will show 20X20 size icon and will look smaller on big screens

abc_iphone6+@3x.png      size 70X70

if(is_iphone4or4s){
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
}
else of (iphone5or6){
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc_iphone5or6.png"];
}
else{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc_iphone6+.png"];
}
```

Please suggest which approach should be used. Should I add only abc.png,abc@2x.png and abc@3x.png or I should use separate retina and non retina image for each resolution?

Thanks

Comment: You should use the first approach, you don'y need the if statements. Let the iPhone do the work for you. That's what the naming convention is for.

Comment: Use the first approach. The sizes don't have to be proportional, but they usually are. Also, if you're only supporting iOS 7 you can just mame an xcassets file.

Answer (score -1):

Which approach to use is depend your need:

Use **approach One** when you need to show **icon of same size in all devices**, this is the best way.

Use **approach Two** when you need to show **icon with different sizes for different screen sizes**.

If your requirement is to use approach Two then consider following points:

```
To Display icon of size 20X20 in iPhone4/4s

abc.png         size 20X20

abc@2x.png      size 40X40

To Display icon of 25X25 in iPhone5/6

abc_iphone5or6.png      size 50X50

To Display icon of size 35X35 in iPhone+

abc_iphone6Plus.png      size 70X70
```